# vertical and horizontal scroll collectionView select cell issue

Tags: swift, collectionview

I have a double direction scrolling collectionView and I want to a cell backgroundView to appear when selected and to disappear when deselected.
I declared an array with selected indexPaths to test on it in the cellForItemAt indexPath func but it doesn't work.Any help please !
This is my code:

```
    var selectedIndexPaths:[IndexPath]=[]

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)){
        selectedIndexPaths=selectedIndexPaths.filter { $0 != indexPath }
    } 
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
 collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // swiftlint:disable force_cast
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier,
                                               for: indexPath) as! UserCollectionCell

    if(selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) ){
        cell.backgroundView?.isHidden=false
    }
    else{
        cell.backgroundView?.isHidden=true
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath)){
        selectedIndexPaths=selectedIndexPaths.filter { $0 != indexPath }
    } 
}
```

it's called when you select a cell and automatically deselects the previously selected one , then change this to

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        selectedIndexPaths = selectedIndexPaths.filter { $0 != indexPath }
    }
    else {
       selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Comment: with your solution the deselected cell don't hide it's background view until you click on it it's not hiding it automatically when you select another cell